# i had run ajax to delete item but after success it stopped working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Below code is the code which is causing the error. After running the Ajax to delete an item, but after success it stops working.

```
<script>
<td><a id="delcon" onclick="delcon()" style="cursor:pointer;"><span class="fa fa-remove"></span></a>
function delcon(){

      var id = $("#itemId").val();

      datavar ='contactid='+id;
      $.ajax(
          {
            url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' =>'mywallets','action' =>'deletecontact'), true); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: datavar,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) 
              {
                  if(data==1)
                  {
                      $("#notifi").html("<p class='alert alert-success'>One Contact Removed</p>");
                      setTimeout(function() {
                            $('#notifi').fadeOut('fast');
                        }, 2000);
                      $("#removerow").hide();

                  }
                  else
                  {
                      $("#notifi").html("<p class='alert alert-danger'>an error occured</p>");
                  }
              }

            }

           );

}
</script>
```

Any pointer is appreciated.

Comment: Please post code as code and style it properly

Comment: `"after success it stopped working"` - Well, your code doesn't *do anything* after the success callback executes.  What would you *expect* it to do?  It's not clear at all what the problem is here.

Comment: i want to delete items in a list by selecting their id...

Comment: @RahulMeemrot: And what's stopping you from doing that?  Try to understand that we're not actually inside your computer watching what you're doing.  You need to be specific about what's happening and what the problem is.

Comment: david now check it

Answer (score 0):

```
         public function deletecontact()
            {
              if($this->request->is('post'))
              {
                $id=$this->request->data['contactid'];
                  $data['Contact']['status']='deactive';
                  $data['Contact']['id']=$id;
                  if($this->Contact->save($data))
                  {
                    echo 1;die;
                  }
              }
            }

    //its my html part
    <input type="hidden" name="" id="itemId" value="<?php echo $cc['Contact']['id']; ?>"> 
          <td><a id="delcon" onclick="delcon()" style="cursor:pointer;"><span class="fa fa-remove"></span></a></td>


    //and this my script


    <script>

    function delcon(){

          var id = $("#itemId").val();

          datavar ='contactid='+id;
          $.ajax(
              {
                url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' =>'mywallets','action' =>'deletecontact'), true); ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: datavar,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) 
                  {
                      if(data==1)
                      {
                          $("#notifi").html("<p class='alert alert-success'>One Contact Removed</p>");
                          setTimeout(function() {
                                $('#notifi').fadeOut('fast');
                            }, 2000);
                          $("#removerow").hide();

                      }
                      else
                      {
                          $("#notifi").html("<p class='alert alert-danger'>an error occured</p>");
                      }
                  }

                }

               );

    }
    </script>

//and php code is here


    public function deletecontact()
    {
      if($this->request->is('post'))
      {
        $id=$this->request->data['contactid'];
          $data['Contact']['status']='deactive';
          $data['Contact']['id']=$id;
          if($this->Contact->save($data))
          {
            echo 1;die;
          }
      }
    }
```